# Azure Mobile App javascript Cordova client

Tags: javascript, cordova, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am developing App using Cordova and want to try using Azure App Service's Mobile App. 
But from this official document

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-xamarin-ios-get-started-preview/

it contains iOS/Xamerin/WinApp/Android but javascript example.

My questions are:

1. Does the javascript version of Azure Mobile App client exist?
2. Is the client SDK the same with Mobile Service javascript client?
3. Is there tutorial of Mobile App javascript client?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the Mobile Apps service is in preview and not all features have been implemented yet.

Yes, the client SDK is the same as with Mobile Services.  If you download the HTML quickstart client from your Mobile App, you'll see that the html page references the same library: *MobileServices.Web-2.0.0-beta.min.js*

You didn't asked for the backend but anyways...Note that a major drawback currently for JS developers is the fact the you can't create a Node backend for Mobile Apps yet.

Comment: yes! MobileServices.Web-2.0.0-beta.min.js works!
Thank you.

Comment: It's a pity that "HTML quickstart client from Azure Mobile App in Azure Portal" is gone.
Hopefully, Microsoft can add the HTML client quickstart sample back to Azure Mobile App.